# Login failed for user 'nostalgic_bohr'. .... Error Number:18456,State:1,Class:14

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, sql-server-2019-express

I am trying to connect and use CRUD operations on a ms sql server with sql server authentication which is run in a docker container (created from this docker image
mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest).

My problem seems to be logging into the docker container of ms sql server(can be seen on github).

The C# WEB API (https://github.com/maxi376/webAPIc-) works perfectly with a local instance of the ms sql database with windows authentication.

Here I have logs of the errors(.html) in my github rep: https://github.com/maxi376/webAPIc- .

Although I can connect to the container just fine using ms sql server management studio.

It worked just fine when the server was local,not in the docker container .But even though I tried so many variations of the ConnectionString (with and without "Trust Server Certificate=true" and/or "Trusted_Connection=True") it is just impossible for me to get it to work.
Kinda desperate for help here(I am even considering working with postgresql and I must containarize the backend and the database)

Comment: As per your error, few things need to check, while running docker command `docker run` what did you pass your sql password? In which format? The error you are getting is related to login failure. Are you passing `sa` `admin` credential? confirm above things before trying. In addition, please make sure you have  configured to use SQL Server Authentication mode.

Comment: docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Password1!" -e "MSSQL_PID=Express" -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest

Comment: Executed above command using bash or powershell? Which authentication mode is enabled on your SQL Server? By the way, have you checked that sql server instance is running within docker image which you have mounted?

Comment: I do not now how to verify the authentication mode enabled on my docker container with the ms sql server,I have no idea
yes the container had been build and was running 100%. the executed command was run using simple powershell

Comment: It has normal settings and normally on Windows 10 I can connect by either windows authentication or SQL server authentication

Answer (score 0):

can you try in code
`EXPOSE 80` under

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

ENV ConnectionStrings:MagsConnectionAzSql="Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Database=db;Trusted_Connection=True;User ID=ENVID;Password=ENVPW;Integrated Security=false;"    
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
ENV DB_UserId="xxxx"
ENV DB_PW="xxxx"

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WEBapi/WEBapi.csproj", "WEBapi/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WEBapi/WEBapi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WEBapi"
RUN dotnet build "WEBapi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WEBapi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WEBapi.dll"]
```

maybe TLS protocol question

Comment: Sir, I do not understand what part of the code you are reffering to

Comment: I modify code. can you try in code

Comment: I am connecting to a ms sql server. In the DB_UserId do I need to use "dbuser"?

Comment: because unable to confirm the Error, please try to Connect the string syntax .reference :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver16&pivots=cs1-bash